# SSL certificate for VPS

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

I have recently bought a web server where I issued SSL certificate and I also bought my domain. I also have VPS server where my API will be located and accessed from the web server. Now the question is this -- is there any way I can use my automatically generated SSL certicate for my VPS server as well?

I added domain like xxx.yyyy.sk and forwarded it to my VPS IP address. When I tried SSL https:// I just received an error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. (this happened while I used my automatically generated certificate)

I also tried issuing certificate on my own in my VPS server using OpenSSL but it seems like I have overwritten my automatically generated certificate because now the certificate is valid but browser says it's not secure..

Is there any way to prevent this 'not secure' status? It's quite annyoing and I want to get rid of it since I am building an e-shop and it would not be appropriate for users to see 'not secure' once they fill in sensitive data.

Thank you for any sensible answers!

Comment: Try https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to generate a certificate with letsencrypt.

```sh
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d xxx.yyyy.sk
```

Comment: When I'm done with it, can I include it in my NodeJS app?